# saving check box values to the database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

I'm new to laravel. I'm saving some checkbox value to the database using loop the loop work but it only saves the last value in the array to the database.

this is my form

```
<form action="{{url('resortf')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input hidden name="h_id" value="{{ $hotel->id}}">
            @foreach($facility as $facilities)
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="{{$facilities->image}}" width="50px" height="50px;">
                <label>{{$facilities->name}}</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{$facilities->id}}" name="facilities[]">
            </div>
            @endforeach
            <div class="row">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Next">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-success" value="Reset">
            </div>

        </form>
```

form working fine; `$facilities` and `$hotel` are passed from the controller.

this is the store function

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $resortfacility = new Resortfacility;
    $loop = $request->get('facilities'); 
    
    foreach ($loop as $value){
        $resortfacility->h_id = $request->get('h_id');
        $resortfacility->f_id = $value;
        
        $resortfacility->save();

    }
}
```

is there any other way to do this that works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem occurs because you create one instance of `Resortfacility`, and then you fill in its values and save. The problem is, every time you perform changes to this object in a loop, you are `updating` existing object and that's why there is only one record in your database, the last one from the loop.

Try making new instance of Resortfacility inside the loop like this:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $loop = $request->get('facilities');
    foreach ($loop as $value){
        $resortfacility = new Resortfacility;
        $resortfacility->h_id = $request->get('h_id');
        $resortfacility->f_id = $value;
        $resortfacility->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct but, bulk insertion might be helpful, as creating new object within foreach loop will make query for every record.

```
     public function store(Request $request) 
     {
             $facilities = $request->get('facilities');
             $data=array();
             foreach($facilities as $facility)
             {
                 $data[] =[
                            'f_id' => $facility,
                            'h_id' => $request->get('h_id'),
                         ];                 
             }
        }

 Resortfacility::insert($data);
```